# Can the shortcuts app in ios 12 be triggered by location (leaving/entering)

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I have been messing with the new IOS shortcuts app--it looks like it might be a reasonable replacement to ITTT with better apple support, but I can't seem to do one thing that should be pretty basic...

I noticed I can create a one-time event that reminds me of something when I leave a location.

I also noticed that I can activate a shortcut to send my wife the ETA when I will arrive home.

I don't see a way to "Trigger" off of map events and feel I’m missing something obvious to accomplish this.

But can I have it send my ETA to my wife whenever I leave the area of my office automatically?

Comment: Hello Bill. You can edit any post without needing “karma” or reputation. Have you found anything that works now on iOS 17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same question. Unfortunately, from what I can find, as of "[right now, Shortcuts can only be triggered manually or by voice](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9goxy7/possible_to_send_a_text_when_passing_a_location/e65ukio/)".

Possible workarounds:

- [Use IFTTT](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9goxy7/possible_to_send_a_text_when_passing_a_location/e666ut6/)
- [Use Launch Center Pro](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9gsbr4/start_shortcuts_automatically/e66j79y/)

Apple tends to release things first with basic functionality and then update and add features as time goes on. We can hope...

Comment: This answer does NOT answer the question - the question asks for an AUTOMATED method. Yes, both of these suggestions allow you to run a location-aware shortcut, but NEITHER allow you to run it without some form of manual intervention part-way through: (IFTTT needs you to manually click an iOS notification; this LCP link - the 'gallery shortcut' mentioned - relies upon you manually starting the iOS shortcut at the outset)

Comment: @Steve, agreed. My answer is not an automated solution but as of right now I do not believe that there is an automated solution to this question. These were the best workarounds that I could find.

Comment: @Steve I thought it answered the question with a no. It was specifically can the shortcuts app be triggered by other things, not looking for an app that can.

Answer (score 2):

I've been researching the same thing - so far with no luck, but close:

Yes, you can use IFTTT to do this:

- "IF" (any trigger, such as location, or by time - from Google Calendar, for example)
- "THAT" running a 'Rich Notification' that includes Apple's shortcut URL notation (shortcuts://open-shortcut?name=[name]), as said above

...however, the Rich Notification just pops up on your iOS device - yes, once you click it it DOES launch the relevant shortcut called [name]
...but - it still relies on you clicking the notificaiton

i.e. still not a fully automated trigger